# Finding approximate value of 'e' in C language

Tags: c, numerical-methods

I am trying to find the approximate value of 'e' using C program. I am getting
the value of e to be true no matter what I enter the value of n. Please let me 
find the error in my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f;
int k;

int factorial (int f);

int main () { 
    int n,i;

    int e = 1;

    printf("Enter the value of n:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        e = e + (1/factorial(i));
    }

    printf("The value of e is %d",e);

    return(0);
}

int factorial (int f) {    
    for (k = 1; k <= f; k++) {
       f = f*k;
    }

    return(p);
}
```

Comment: You know that `e` contains a lot of decimals? How would an *integer* variable be able to have decimals?

Comment: By the way, the code as you show it won't even build. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, your factorial is not properly defined. It will multiply * f twice.

Comment: `1/factorial(i)` is *integer division* with result `0` (except for 1!), even if you have `double e`.

Comment: @VictoriaRuiz: It's worse than twice: it moves the loop bound faster than it catches up to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors.You are adding floating values in an `int` variable! Please read the comments of following code :

```
int k; // remove f

int factorial (int f);

int main () {

int n,i;

float e=1; // take e as float/double, not int

printf("Enter the value of n:");

scanf("%d",&n);

for (i=1 ; i<=n ; i++) {

    e=e+(1.0/factorial(i)); // take 1.0 (floating value) instead of 1 (integer value)
}

printf("The value of e is %f",e);

return(0);
}

int factorial (int f) {
    int total=1; // initialize total with 1
    for (k=1 ; k<=f ; k++) {

        total=total*k; // here is a big mistake in your code. You incremented value of f in every iteration. Try to print value of f after every iteration to find your error.
    }

    return(total);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you must use floating point variables. Another problem is that the factorial function will overflow after 12! Additionally it is a waste of processing power to continually re-compute the factorial. This shows a more efficient way to implement the Taylor series, by building on the previous term. This sidesteps the problem of calculating the factorial too.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double e, term;
    int t, n;

    printf("Enter the value of n:");
    if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    e = 1;
    term = 1;
    for(t = 1; t <= n; t++) {
        term /= t;
        e += term;
    }
    printf("%.15f\n", e);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output using the maximum `n` your program could handle

```
Enter the value of n:12
2.718281828286169
```

Whereas in `math.h` it is

```
2.718281828459045...
```

Which is not very accurate. This example allows a more accurate value to be obtained:

```
Enter the value of n:20
2.718281828459046
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double factorial (int f) {
    double p = 1;
    for (k = 1; k <= f; k++) {
        p = p*k; // f = f * k;
    }

    return p; // what is p doing here? (in original code)
}
```

Your problem is that you are changing the value of `f` apart from that other mistakes are already explained. it should return `double` and some other mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

For an accurate `float` estimation,

```
e = (((((((((1.f / 11 + 1) / 10 + 1) / 9 + 1 ) / 8 + 1) / 7 + 1) / 6 + 1) / 5 + 1) / 4 + 1) / 3 + 1) / 2 + 2
```

The initial `.f` is essential.

---

It is much better to accumulate from the smallest values.